# Detecting pieces of a Version 1 QR code and processing the assembled version

Tags: computer-vision

I am building an aerial robot that needs to be able to detect pieces of a QR code (examples below) and combine them to process the information contained in the fully assembled QR code.  I don't have much experience with CV and am not sure where to start.  Does anyone have any ideas about how I might go about doing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this may help ... https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/ ... rotate the image until it is smallest in size

Comment: The problem is I’m not sure how to find the corners of the QR pieces... once I do that i can do a perspective transform and rotate, as you suggested.

Comment: use google ... `cv detect square object` returns this https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: this is sort of related ... http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/

Comment: http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017/papers/DeGol_ChromaTag_A_Colored_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf

Comment: I’ll look into artoolkit.  Thanks

Comment: Similar to artoolkit is also arUco https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26 . And as you can see from their page you can detect also different dictionaries with this library (including artoolkit). It is opensource and you can checkout their code, maybe the function detectMarkers() may give you some hints.